# Moving window with complete boundary in Python

Tags: python, image, matrix, numpy

I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27996481/moving-window-with-complete-boundary-in-python) question a few days ago. The question is about producing moving/rolling windows of an array in Python as in the following example:

```
from skimage.util import view_as_windows
view_as_windows(np.arange(10*10).reshape(10,10), (4,4),4)

Out[14]:
array([[[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
         [10, 11, 12, 13],
         [20, 21, 22, 23],
         [30, 31, 32, 33]],

        [[ 4,  5,  6,  7],
         [14, 15, 16, 17],
         [24, 25, 26, 27],
         [34, 35, 36, 37]]],


       [[[40, 41, 42, 43],
         [50, 51, 52, 53],
         [60, 61, 62, 63],
         [70, 71, 72, 73]],

        [[44, 45, 46, 47],
         [54, 55, 56, 57],
         [64, 65, 66, 67],
         [74, 75, 76, 77]]]]).
```

However, this removes elements of the original arrays that don't fit into another window. It was suggested that I should fill the arrays with zeros in order to get a full window, so I wrote the following code for doing so and I thought it would be nice to have a review in case I missed corner cases:

```
import numpy as np

def extend_image(image, steps=16):
    # Required number of rows
    required_rows = np.mod(image.shape[0], steps)
    # Required number of columns
    required_cols = np.mod(image.shape[1], steps) 
    # Concatenate original array with rows filled with zeros 
    partial = np.concatenate((image, np.zeros((required_rows,image.shape[1])))) 
    # Concatenate partial array with columns filled with zeros
    extended = np.concatenate((partial, np.zeros((partial.shape[0], required_cols))), axis=1) 
    return extended
```

This should work as follows:

```
view_as_windows(extend_image(np.arange(10*10).reshape(10,10), steps=4), (4,4),4)

array([[[[  0.,   1.,   2.,   3.],
         [ 10.,  11.,  12.,  13.],
         [ 20.,  21.,  22.,  23.],
         [ 30.,  31.,  32.,  33.]],

        [[  4.,   5.,   6.,   7.],
         [ 14.,  15.,  16.,  17.],
         [ 24.,  25.,  26.,  27.],
         [ 34.,  35.,  36.,  37.]],

        [[  8.,   9.,   0.,   0.],
         [ 18.,  19.,   0.,   0.],
         [ 28.,  29.,   0.,   0.],
         [ 38.,  39.,   0.,   0.]]],


       [[[ 40.,  41.,  42.,  43.],
         [ 50.,  51.,  52.,  53.],
         [ 60.,  61.,  62.,  63.],
         [ 70.,  71.,  72.,  73.]],

        [[ 44.,  45.,  46.,  47.],
         [ 54.,  55.,  56.,  57.],
         [ 64.,  65.,  66.,  67.],
         [ 74.,  75.,  76.,  77.]],

        [[ 48.,  49.,   0.,   0.],
         [ 58.,  59.,   0.,   0.],
         [ 68.,  69.,   0.,   0.],
         [ 78.,  79.,   0.,   0.]]],


       [[[ 80.,  81.,  82.,  83.],
         [ 90.,  91.,  92.,  93.],
         [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.]],

        [[ 84.,  85.,  86.,  87.],
         [ 94.,  95.,  96.,  97.],
         [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.]],

        [[ 88.,  89.,   0.,   0.],
         [ 98.,  99.,   0.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.]]]])
```

Comment: Is this a typo? `np.mod(img.shape[1], steps)` I don't see "img" anywhere else, only "image"

Comment: Yes, that is a typo. I will correct it in a moment.

Answer (score 2):

`numpy` has a `pad` function.  It has many options, but this extends your array from a `(10,10)` to `(12,12)`, which can be partitioned a 3x3 set of `(4,4)` windows.

```
np.pad(A,((0,2),(0,2)),mode='constant',constant_values=0)

array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,  0,  0],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19,  0,  0],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29,  0,  0],
       [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39,  0,  0],
       [40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49,  0,  0],
       [50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59,  0,  0],
       [60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69,  0,  0],
       [70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79,  0,  0],
       [80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89,  0,  0],
       [90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]])
```

Your 'extend' returns a (20,20) array.  `extend_image(A,steps=12).astype(int)[:12,:12]` produces the same `(12,12)`.  It is faster than `np.pad` (by about 30%).

`numpy/lib/arraypad.py` contains `pad` and the functions it uses, it you want to learn from it.  Looks like it uses `np.concatenate`.

In this case of just padding with 0s, here's an even faster (but not as general) a solution:

```
def foo(A,step=2):
    shape=(A.shape[0]+step,A.shape[1]+step)
    A1=np.zeros(shape, A.dtype)
    A1[:A.shape[0], :A.shape[1]] = A
    return A1
```

Comment: Very nice to know about `np.pad`. Thanks!

Comment: I added a faster, though less general solution.

Comment: You can still pass a `constant_values` argument to your function `foo` and instead of using zeros, use `A1=np.ones(shape, A.dtype)*constant_values`, right?

Comment: @hpaulj - gladly upvoted your answer. I have a moving window as well and the  value depends on prev and next i.e val = curr + prev + next. So I have 3 moving windows but this leaves out the first and last value. So I can now pad this by 1 and calculate the boundary values.